# Incorrect time string with NSDateFormatter with Daylight Saving Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm using `CET` as my default `timezone` in my application. In Germany `Daylight` saving time will start from **29 March 2015**. Now I'm doing some testing to see if my dates will be converted correctly in the future. I used following code to test it.

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CET"];
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:timeZone];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; // 10 Feb, 2015
NSDate *dateAfter29March = [now dateByAddingMonths:2]; // 10 April, 2015

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

NSLog(@" NOW DATE -> %@",[formatter stringFromDate:now]);
NSLog(@" DATE AFTER 29 March -> %@",[formatter stringFromDate:dateAfter29March]);
```

The category method for adding months is

```
- (NSDate *)dateByAddingMonths:(NSInteger) dMonths {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.month = dMonths;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:self options:0];
}
```

The Output of Console is as follows:

```
NOW DATE -> 2015-02-10 18:28:05 +0100
DATE AFTER 29 March -> 2015-04-10 18:28:05 +0200
```

Where my expected time on date after 29 March was 17:28:05 as One hour in now less after daylight time. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I also tried to set the output strings in a label and no change occurs.

Comment: Show the code for `dateByAddingMonths:`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is your method `dateByAddingMonths:`. I tried `var dateAfter29March = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(2*30*24*60*60)` in playground, it works fine (shows: `"Apr 11, 2015, 7:49 PM"`, where now = `Feb 10, 2015, 6:53 PM"`).

Comment: @Q80 Never use such code to add a time interval.

Comment: @AbidHussain Add some NSLog statements to log `now` and `dateAfter29March` in addition to logging the corresponding strings.

Comment: It's recommended in WWDC sessions. You can't go to next day by adding 86400 secs. It's wrong.

Comment: I understand it's "wrong". The problem you have is simple math. Do you want to go to some exact point in time in future (letting the system take care of the conversions and the leap years, daylight savings, etc for you)? Or you want to go some exact seconds ahead?

Comment: @rmaddy printing direct date objects yields expected results. i.e. [NOW DATE -> 2015-02-10 18:00:55 +0000] and [DATE AFTER 30 March -> 2015-04-10 17:00:55 +0000]. So problem happens at dateformatter string conversion.

Comment: Why have you called '[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:timeZone];'? Can you show the result removing this line? Because I think, your default time zone should be GMT and while formatting the date, you may change the timezone to any.

Comment: @Shoaib that's because I always want to show Berlin time regardless of user's location or device timezone. Secondly removing this line and setting my system's timezone to Berlin doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't see what you are complaining about.

You asked the OS to add two months to a date. And adding two months means that it uses the calendar, and returns a date that is two months later, on the same day of the month, at the same time. It *should* take changes in DST into account, and it does. That's what adding two months means.

Imagine we have a meeting that we always do at the first of the month, at 10am in the morning. You want that meeting at 10am in the morning, whether it is DST or not.

Comment: I like that meeting example. Since I ran into DST problems, I don't like DST any more. Before that I was neutral. PostgreSQL stores timezone data at least, MySQL doesn't :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; // 10 Feb, 2015
NSDate *dateAfter29March = [self dateByAddingMonths:2 date:now]; // 10 April, 2015


NSLog(@"now -> %@", now);
NSLog(@"dateAfter29March -> %@", dateAfter29March);
NSLog(@"========================================");


NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CET"];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

NSLog(@"NOW DATE -> %@",[formatter stringFromDate:now]);
NSLog(@"DATE AFTER 29 March -> %@",[formatter stringFromDate:dateAfter29March]);
```

It worked fine for me. See the logs

```
now -> 2015-02-11 06:01:56 +0000
dateAfter29March -> 2015-04-11 06:01:56 +0000
========================================
NOW DATE -> 2015-02-11 07:01:56 +0100
DATE AFTER 29 March -> 2015-04-11 08:01:56 +0200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition to find out when is the next daylight saving time transition for your time zone:

```
NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "CET")!.nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition!   // "Mar 28, 2015, 22:00"
```

You can create a NSDateFormatter extension to format your time using the CET time zone as follow:

```
extension NSDate {
    var time:String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "CET")
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}



let futureDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 3, day: 27, hour: 13, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
let futureDateDLST = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 3, day: 29, hour: 13, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!

futureDate.time      // 17:00"
futureDateDLST.time  // "18:00"
```