# Is there a daylight savings check in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsdate, dst

I need to check to see if the current date is during daylight savings time. In pseudocode that would be like this:

```
let date = NSDate()

if date.isDaylightSavingsTime {

    print("Success")

}
```

I haven't been able to find the solution to this anywhere on the internet.

Comment: As `NSDate()` is a foundation class and takes, in essence, the same methods and arguments for Swift and Obj-C, the following thread should be able to help you out (obj-c): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438156/incorrect-time-string-with-nsdateformatter-with-daylight-saving-time . See, specifically, LeoDabus answer, which is using swift (and `NSTimeZone`)

Comment: @dfri http://stackoverflow.com/a/27053592/2303865

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An `NSDate` alone represents an absolute point in time.
To decide if a date is during daylight savings time or not
it needs to be interpreted in the context of a *time zone*.

Therefore you'll find [that method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimeZone/isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:) in the `NSTimeZone` class and not
in the `NSDate` class. Example:

```
let date = NSDate()

let tz = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
if tz.isDaylightSavingTimeForDate(date) {

}
```

---

**Update for Swift 3/4:**

```
let date = Date()

let tz = TimeZone.current
if tz.isDaylightSavingTime(for: date) {
    print("Summertime, and the livin' is easy ... ")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.0 or later**

You can check a date isDaylightSavingTime in two ways by time zone [identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone/2293601-identifier) or [abbreviation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone/2293351-abbreviation).

```
let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/New_York")!
if timeZone.isDaylightSavingTime(for: Date()) {
   print("Yes, daylight saving time at a given date")        
}
```

```
let timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")!
if timeZone.isDaylightSavingTime(for: Date()) {
   print("Yes, daylight saving time at a given date")     
}
```