# getting nil date from string using formatter

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm using this code for converting array of `String` date into `Date`

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
for i in 0 ..< data.count {
     let time = data[i]
     let ft_date = time["ft_date"] as! String
     print(ft_date)
     let dateF = formatter.date(from: ft_date)
     print(dateF)
}
```

and it's the output of console

```
2017-04-09T00:00:00
Optional(2017-04-08 19:30:00 +0000)
2017-04-08T00:00:00
Optional(2017-04-07 19:30:00 +0000)
2017-04-05T00:00:00
Optional(2017-04-04 19:30:00 +0000)
2017-04-01T00:00:00
Optional(2017-03-31 19:30:00 +0000)
2017-04-01T00:00:00
Optional(2017-03-31 19:30:00 +0000)
2017-04-01T00:00:00
Optional(2017-03-31 19:30:00 +0000)
2017-03-22T00:00:00
nil
```

why this is happening? it's the same format but I'm getting nil

Comment: I can't reproduce...

Comment: I'm confused too it's correct logically but happening @Sweeper

Comment: have you checked for day light saving ?

Comment: no I didn't. how can I do that? @Lion

Comment: We can reproduce this by setting the timeZone like formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "IRST").....here IRST is an abbreviation for Iran standard time, if we set the timeZone to Iran Daylight time("IRDT") issue is not reproducible.

Comment: so if set it to `IRDT` it will not happen again? on any other date? @user3608500

Comment: See [1st april dates of 80s failed to parse in iOS 10.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284272/1st-april-dates-of-80s-failed-to-parse-in-ios-10-0) (duplicate?) for a similar issue and a possible solution.

Comment: thanks that solved @MartinR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you living in a country where daylight saving time changes on `2017-03-22` at midnight?

If yes this could be the reason because the date does not exist.

Comment: I'm living in Iran and it's not changing on `2017-03-22` but how can I fix it?

Comment: According to [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/iran) it does change on `2017-03-22` in Iran

Comment: oh you're right. what should I do?

Comment: Daylight starts on 22 March 2017 in Iran as linked [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/iran/tehran). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34533387/3581421) answer may help you.

Comment: my date is String so I can't use `isDaylightSavingTimeForDate` because it gets a `NSDate`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change time Format ;

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
```

[image]

Comment: how do u say this `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z` is equilant to `2017-03-22T00:00:00` returns nil

Comment: @Amir_P - i am not seen any change for your date format

Comment: what you mean? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Amir_P - i said every thing is correct, check once your code again

Comment: the format you said is not working

Comment: I checked it many times but it's not working @Anbu.Karthik